# Unable to install on UEFI anymore

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, bios, acer

I have an Acer Aspire E15 Start computer with which I have had a problem for a long time and which I cannot solve today.

One day I tried to install the latest version of the Debian operating system on this computer (I was using the GUI installation mode). Everything was going right.

The section to install GRUB arrives. It asks me to enter the partition to which I want to install GRUB, which I chose /dev/sda.

At that moment, I get a message similar to this:

[image: Force UEFI]

I am not going to lie. I didn't know what you meant by "Force UEFI installation" So I selected yes.

After that, when the installation is finished, the computer restarts (as is normal) and since then, when I boot the computer in UEFI, I don't stop getting this message:

[image: DEFAULT BOOT MEDIA]

When I try to install any operating system, be it Windows or Linux in this way (I mean, in UEFI), at the end of the installation, this message always appears, and it's frustrating because I don't know what the error is.

I decided to take it to a computer store. I asked them to install a light operating system that I knew from Linux, which was Q4OS.

When the computer was returned to me, the operating system was installed correctly in UEFI, but something was wrong. In the "Boot Order" of the BIOS, there was an entry that I had never seen and it was placed first.

**"EFI Boot File 0: Q4OS"**

Turns out, I thought the UEFI was fixed, so I tried to install Debian again like I used to before all this stuff, and it got screwed again. I kept getting the message in blue.

I've seen many tutorials on YT saying that the solution is to move from UEFI to Legacy.

Right now, I have Arch Linux installed in Legacy (More than anything because it's faster) but it's terrible, because the BOOT graphics look super bad and it takes longer to load than in UEFI.

I would like to know if there is any solution to fix this, obviously ruling out continuing to install in Legacy or take it back to the computer store (they charge you a fortune)

If they could do it at the computer store, I would like to know how I could do it.

All the best!

Comment: Try to set the EFI file as trusted in the boot options of your BIOS as explained [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289754&p=13334180#post13334180) by oldfred. It seems you need to set and enter a supervisor password in your BIOS, otherwise you won't be able to select this option.

Comment: You should not mix BIOS & UEFI installs. And with Linux you may have either MBR or gpt partitioning. The only time to have MBR(msdos) is if your system is over 10 years old and your are installing Windows in BIOS mode. Backup Arch and either convert to UEFI or erase it. Convert drive to gpt if it is not already. And create an ESP - efi system partition. Then only install in UEFI boot mode. Since Acer you may need "trust" setting. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 1):

You were right!
Here is the solution!

1. Go to BIOS
2. Security Menu
3. "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"
4. Select the `grubx64.efi` file

That's it!